# Wrong compiled [civicrm.files] variable in Resources URL

Tags: directory, resource-urls

My issue is [civicrm.files] variable in Resources URL contains full real absolute path on our server '/var/www..' etc.

It constructs as such:

`https://www.website.com/var/www/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/`

All variables in Upload Directories currently set as portable.

[image: Upload Directories Settings]

I'm using CiviCRM 5.14.3 on Wordpress 5.1

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when your site directory is using symbolic link. To fix the variables you will need to make sure that the docroot specified in apache/ngnix config should match exactly with $civicrm_root and CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR in civicrm.settings.php.

Try updating if its different and clear CiviCRM cache.

Cheers

Pradeep